# Using selected features from a wrapper algorithm to train another model

Tags: classification, feature-selection

I was wondering if it can be useful to use selected features from a wrapper algorithm (for example SVM-RFE) to train another classification model like k-NN or Linear regression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this question is too general, and the answer depends too much on data at hand and on the context of your specific problem.

One note thought. In general what means "an important feature" for a model or algorithm, might not be the same for another model. One model might be able to represent knowledge in a way that could not be exploited by another model.

More than that, what is called Rashomon effect describes in a very effective way how this feature importance could change drastically after applying feature selection for the same procedure. For more information on Rashomon effect in Breiman interpretation see [this paper](http://faculty.smu.edu/tfomby/eco5385/lecture/Breiman%27s%20Two%20Cultures%20paper.pdf).

Taking these problems into account, I tried to imagine how an argument against "usefulness" would look like, I see nothing there ... It involves a lot of risks, but I suppose there are situations when it pays the whole effort.